# TamperMonkey EventListener on button not working

Tags: javascript, dom, event-listener, tampermonkey

I created this snippet:

```
function addClick(button, container) {
    console.log("In add click");
    const data = container.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].innerHTML;
    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        alert('clicked')
        console.log("Clicked");
    })
}

function createCopyButtons(array){
    array.forEach(element => {

        const container = document.createElement('div');
        const button = document.createElement('button');

        button.innerHTML = "Copy"
        
        styleContainer(container);
        styleButton(button, element);
        stylePrevious(element);
        
        container.innerHTML = element.outerHTML + button.outerHTML;

        element.parentNode.replaceChild(container, element);

        addClick(button, container); 

    });
}
```

Now in here the array is the array of DOM elements I want this property to apply and I call the createCopyButtons() function down with some more stuff. Now the thing is that this event listener does not apply or does not work. I tried to wait till the document is loaded by these answers and only then apply my javascript snippet but the event listener doesn't seems to work.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  //do work
});

if (document.readyState == "complete") {
     // document is ready. Do your stuff here
   }
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update:

```js
function addClick(button) {
    button.addEventListener('click', ()=>{
        console.log("Clicked");
    })
}

let p = document.querySelectorAll('p');

// innerHTML not work
let btn1 = document.createElement('button');
btn1.innerHTML = "Not work";
p[0].innerHTML = btn1.outerHTML;
addClick(btn1)

// work
let btn2 = document.createElement('button');
btn2.innerHTML = "work";
p[1].appendChild(btn2);
addClick(btn2)
```

```html
<p></p>
<p></p>
```

---

because you append the button to the container using string `(.innerHTML)` not DOM or using `appendChild()`

```
container.innerHTML = element.outerHTML + button.outerHTML
```

the following function will not apply the event

```
addClick(button, container);
```

I don't know why you need to wrap target element and the button inside `div`, why not just append the button after target element using or `insertBefore()` or `insertAdjacentHTML()` but below is working code that follow yours.

it find the button inside the `container` for using as `addClick()` parameters

```js
function addClick(button, container) {
  console.log("In add click");
  const data = container.nextElementSibling.childNodes[0].innerHTML;

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    alert('clicked')
    console.log("Clicked");
  })
}

function createCopyButtons(array) {
  array.forEach(element => {

    const container = document.createElement('div');
    let button = document.createElement('button');

    button.innerHTML = "Copy"

    container.innerHTML = element.outerHTML + button.outerHTML;

    element.parentNode.replaceChild(container, element);

    let btn = container.querySelector('button'); // <== find the button
    addClick(btn, btn.parentNode);

  });
}
createCopyButtons(document.querySelectorAll('input'))
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="text">
  <p><span>test</span></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir it not like i added the button on my container and then to DOM and then i have a reference to the object button in my already so I take that reference and set the property onclick? Why is it wrong?

Comment: read again first paragraph in my answer, in other words you need like `container.appendChild(button)` to make `addClick(button, container); ` work

Comment: Sorry but I still don't understand. If I put it as a inner html and bind an event listener then what am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you put it as innerHTML it only copy text of an element but not the event listener. answer updated, I have added example above

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you sir.